# Display correct username in label in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am getting my last name back as `"Webster"` but I would like to get `NSantagata` (first initial of my first name and last name) or `Fieldaero\nicola.santagata`.

How could I do that?
This is the code I have:

In the **Controller:**

```
var userName = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
ViewBag.Name = userName;
```

In the **View**:

```
@Html.Label((string)ViewBag.Name)
```

If I do it directly from the view with code `@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`
I get what I want, that is `Fieldaero\nicola.santagata`,  but I do not know how to get the same result in the controller.  I will then use the value in the controller to execute other code.

Comment: This feels like we need more information on the `LastName` and `FirstName` properties from some object

Comment: The viewbag.name is probably overwritten somewhere in the the pipeline. Lesson 1 in asp.net mvc: NEVER use the "viewbag", make a viewmodel.

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what I could do to get "NSantagata"  or  "Fieldaero\nicola.santagata"  back?  I will display that in the label.  Thank you.